# Unity | Label width

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, label, width

I want to get the size of my label. It doesn't work like it should. It gets the size, but only for the standard fontsize. But I'm not using the standard one.

Could this be a problem: "Unable to find style 'FontStyle' in skin 'GameSkin' Repaint UnityEngine.GUISkin:GetStyle(String)"

I have this code:
    string test ="test"; 
    Vector2 SizeVect;
    public int FontSize = 1;
    Rect TestRect:

```
void OnGUI(){
   TestRect = new Rect(...);
   FontStyle = new GUIStyle();
   FontStyle.fontSize = FontSize;
   SizeVect = GUI.skin.GetStyle("FontStyle").CalcSize(new GUIContent(test));
   GUI.Label(TestRect, test, FontStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUISkin-label.html).

```
SizeVect = GUI.skin.label.CalcSize(new GUIContent(test));
```

Update: When font size is changed, this also works.

```
private float fontSize = 12;
void OnGUI()
{
    fontSize = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(50, 50, 200, 20), fontSize, 8, 64);

    var str = "ABCDEFG";
    var style = GUI.skin.label;
    style.fontSize = (int)fontSize;
    var size = style.CalcSize(new GUIContent(str));
    var rect = new Rect(100, 100, size.x, size.y);
    GUI.Label(rect,str );
    GUI.Box(rect,"");
}
```

See snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: @user3050346, it worked fine even when font size is used. See the update!